# Angular2. insert text {{someText}} in DOM and force to interpolate it

Tags: angular, angular5

Is there any way to insert code in DOM and force to interpolate it. In this variant I insert text "`{{name}}`" to div ant it stays just "`{{name}}`" in view. Code and link to plunker is below.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: `
  <div #myId></div>
 `,
})

export class App  implements ngAfterViewInit {
 name:string = 'hello world';
 constructor(myElement: ElementRef) {}

 @ViewChild('myId') myDiv:ElementRef; 

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myDiv.nativeElement.innerHTML = '{{name}}' // I want this to be 'hello world' in View

 }
}
```

Here is a link to current code
https://plnkr.co/edit/VYltGSDqVRar0Z2aqRln?p=preview

***p.s.*** I know this code may look strange and not in Agular way, but this is just simplified version of my issue. I'm stuck with angular-datatables, which has troubles with rendering `{{interpolation}}`. https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1131

Comment: You can compile a component at runtime, otherwise this is not supported, because normally all binding syntax is converted to JS when you build your Angular application (even before you deploy it) and at runtime such bindings are ignored by Angular.

Comment: @Ric OP wants to _bind_ the variable not just set the value in innerHtml..

Comment: @SurajRao ah I see, my bad, wasn't quite sure what OP wanted, either the binding or simply setting the text value.

Comment: Maybe you can create a component with this and load it dynamically: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader but I don't know if this approach fits to your needs.